# Loop to fill matrix by row in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix, row

I know this is a very basic question, but I can't seem to find a direct answer anywhere. My real code is performing some calculations on a list of spatial polygon data frames, then slotting the metrics calculated into a pre-allocated matrix. My problem is that when I call the matrix after the loop again, it's still empty. I've created toy code that maintains this issue.

```
#create the columns to be filled
empty<-matrix(,nrow=4,ncol=3)
colnames(empty)<-c("NF", "PF", "AA")

lapply(1:4, function(x){
  NF<-2
  #Proportion of forest
  PF<- 4
  #Average fragment area
  AA<- 6
  #plug them into my awaiting columns
  empty[x,]<-c(NF, PF, AA)
})

head(empty)
```

returns

```
     NF PF AA
[1,] NA NA NA
[2,] NA NA NA
[3,] NA NA NA
[4,] NA NA NA
```

Comment: `empty` is only updated within the scope of the `lapply` call and never returned. Therefore, nothing changes in the `empty` stored in your global environment. Change your `lapply` to an explicit `for` loop and it should work okay.

Comment: `matrix(c(2,4,6), 4, 3, TRUE, list(NULL, c("NF", "PF", "AA")))`

Comment: golf `matrix(1:3*2,4,3,T,list({},c("NF","PF","AA")))` or `rbind(c(NF=2,PF=4,AA=6))[rep(1,4),]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you fill in the matrix within `lapply` which does not work. You could do instead:

```
l <- lapply(1:4, function(x){
  NF<-2
  PF<- 4
  AA<- 6
  c(NF, PF, AA)
})

m <- matrix(unlist(l), ncol = 3, byrow = T)
colnames(m) <- c("NF", "PF", "AA")

#     NF PF AA
#[1,]  2  4  6
#[2,]  2  4  6
#[3,]  2  4  6
#[4,]  2  4  6
```

Its more efficient as you do not grow the matrix within a loop.